# Laptop LCD video cable extension

Tags: distance, lvds

How long that cable:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32885352799.html
can be extended without losing image quality if I cut it in the middle and add wire?
Which wire will fit and what kind is the shielding ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Separate the laptop screen from the keyboard?

Comment: Separate the screen from the laptop for the longest distance using lvds cable passively

Comment: This doesn't sound like a great idea. Why not use another display and connect it with HDMI or some other conventional interface?

Comment: The reason is trying to avoid high rf emission from the hdmi cable connector / controller board / screen